# How to setup 2 services with same IP?

Tags: dns, port, domain, domain-name

I had 2 services on a server that run on 2 different ports. one of them on port 80 and another on port 3000. I want to address them with the same IP like this:

http://xxx.ttt.yy : the one that runs on port 3000

http://xxx.ttt.yy/zzz : the one that runs on port 80

what should I do?

Comment: What operating system and which web server?

Comment: @harrymc 
OS : linux(debian) WS: apache

Comment: @harrymc And if it help, I run Filerun on port 80 and swagger-ui on port 3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this with HTTP, you need to run a *reverse proxy* software (e.g. nginx or Apache with the mod_proxy_http module) on port 80, and configure it to forward requests to other ports.

For example, in nginx,

```
location / { proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; }

location /zzz/ { proxy_pass http://localhost:81; }
```

Note: The service that *currently* uses port 80 will need to be moved to another port first (or at least configured to listen on loopback IP address only).